# Does removing an APK from the Play Store make the applicationId available for submission again?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Let's say I created an APK with the applicationId "com.example.my", and submitted it to the play store.

If I remove that app from the play store after it's been approved, does that make the applicationId available again immediately? Or is this applicationId reserved forever even after it's been deleted?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic